# Восстановить данные после случайной записи образа

Tags: хранение-данных, восстановление

На внешний жесткий диск объемом 1Тб записал, с помощью win32disk imager, образ операционной системы raspbian 16Гб. Случайно. Теперь у меня на диске есть раздел Boot в FAT32 и раздел EXT4, остальное же место обозначено как не распределенное. Подозреваю, что файлы мои там остались, но как их прочитать?

Answer (score 0):

**!** Сделайте образ диска и далее играйтесь уже с ним. Сам диск после этого отключите и отложите пока.

Так как я не специально обученный человек в data recovery, то мои действия были бы такими:

- сначала [testdisc/photorec](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/get-your-data-back-linux-based-data-recovery-tools/)
- потом [Hiren's Boot CD](https://habr.com/ru/post/415593/), там есть recovery утилиты
- если бы ничего не вышло - отнёс бы **клон** к специально обученным людям.